# Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded Error When Finding Shortest Path

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to find the shortest point from source to target but I am getting the error:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Here's my code where neighbors_for_id returns a list of ids of the source's neighbors:

````
    """
    Returns the shortest list of person_ids that connect the source to the target.

    If no possible path, returns None.
    """
    visited = set()
    path = []
    if source == target:
        return path
    while source != target:
        destinations = neighbors_for_id(source)
        for neighbor in destinations:
            path.append(neighbor)
            if neighbor == target:
                return path
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                source = neighbor
                shortest_path(source, target, visited)```
````

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

You are currently (mistakenly) resetting "visited" to an empty set upon entry into the function, even though you are passing it as an argument from the internal call.  This is probably leading to the max depth issue because it can now "ping pong" between 2 neighbors or follow loops in your graph.

when you call the function externally to kick it off, just pass an empty set:

```
shortest_path(source, target, set())
```

You are doing a similar thing with the path list.  You need to pass it along in the recursion so that the next steps will add to the growing list and NOT reset it in the function.  So you are probably going to end up with a new function signature that includes the path.

You could clean it up a bit with defaults such as:

```
def shortest_path(source, target, visited=set(), path=list() ):
```